# Unused parameters in coffeescript callback declarations

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In this coffeescript code, my code inspection tool in RubyMine reports the variable 'textStatus' as unused.

Should textStatus be omitted?

Is there any need for the convention of the '_' ruby placeholder for unused variables?

```
  request.fail (jqXHR, textStatus) ->
    Utils.alert jqXHR.responseText
```

Comment: There's no such convention I know of. However, when not used, the parameter should be omitted - at least for readability concerns.

Comment: mreq, I'm guessing you mean the 'last' parameter when not used.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if it *should* be omitted, or if it *can* be omitted?

It definitely can be omitted, and quite possibly should be omitted. If for some reason you want the reader of the code to know that a text status can be supplied, then you can keep it... but usually, I like to keep the focus on what *I'm* doing with the code, not what I'm not doing.

As far as using `_` to call out a variable you don't use/care about, I've definitely done this myself at times, but only when it's not the last variable in the list. I'm also on the fence about this, given the popularity of the [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/) library.

Comment: Good answer. In terms of the underscore, the specific meaning of the '_' applies to ruby. Any convention for CoffeeScript or JavaScript?

Comment: If you're not using underscore.js, feel free to use '_', I can't think of any other conventions... if I were using underscore.js, I'd probably either use the semantic name, textStatus in this case (and possibly leave a comment mentioning it not being used, if the comment improves readability), or use a single character variable to indicate it being an unimportant local variable.